# What is the maximum limit in HTTP protocol for a POST request/response body's payload. Sending JSON over REST

Tags: java, spring, http, rest, resttemplate

This is not a duplicate question.

I have been googling around and have seen various statements about limits of the HTTP request/response bodies. I am using the RestTemplate of the Spring framework, and am concerned about the size of the json document being exchanged in the request and responses.

I am using tomcat, and I have heard that I can change the http size to as High as I want. But my main concern is Limits of HTTP protocols. Can someone explain please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It wouldn't be a very good http client if it didn't follow the http spec.

Comment: [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/151090/is-there-a-maximum-size-for-content-of-an-http-post) might help. If there is a limit it would be imposed by the server your communicating with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No limit is specified in [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

Comment: @Pacerier (a) Surely you can look them up as easily as I can? (b) It would be rather unprecedented to introduce a limit in any specification that hadn't been there in prior versions.

Comment: Just thought you may had wish to update the question.